# LogIn Page with Registration page Object alternate command question

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to get an alternate solution for this but in the Microsoft Visual studio 2019 software I am not able to do !

```
private static bool NewMethod12(object myclass, LogIn @in)
{
    return Equality Comparer<object>.Default.Equals(
        x: obj.Equals(objA: Convert.ToInt32(value: @in.Equals(**obj**: @in.Label1)) ||
        EqualityComparer<object>.Default.Equals( obj: myclass.Equals(cmd1()),
                                                @in.cmd)));
}
```

Comment: Please don't assume all the users here are male; there are plenty of other users of other genders that use Stack Overflow too. Also what is your question here exactly? "Looking for an alternative" doesn't tell us anything about what the problem with what you have.

Comment: Sorry, Madam ! I changed as Sir or Madam please see my question share your view with answer which I suggest as experts opinion ! Thank You .!

Comment: I never said I was a madam either... Just *don't* assume the genders of the users here; you *did* agree to that when you created your account

Comment: As for your question, I can't answer it; you've incorrect tagging of [tag:sql-server] brought the question to my attention, and hence why I removed  the tag.

Comment: Sorry as I wrongly put <Sql Server> Tag . Please post  me a suggestion !